# Casting String to Charsequence

Tags: java, string, casting, charsequence

What is the purpose of casting `String` to `CharSequence` explicitly?
`String` itself implements `CharSequence` interface.

Spring 4.x supports Java 6+ and `CharSequence` is present since 1.4.

Code snippet from Spring Framework:

```
public static boolean hasText(String str) {
    // Why do we cast str to CharSequence? 
    return hasText((CharSequence) str);
}

public static boolean hasText(CharSequence str) {
    if (!hasLength(str)) {
        return false;
    }

    int strLen = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So that it won't recurse infinitely. The method could actually be removed. It is probably only there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: kind of tricky method overloading...

Comment: @EJP, oh..so we do it to point compiler that we want to execute method specific to `CharSequence` parameter. Thank you.

Comment: @EJP this is the right answer. You should post it so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I do agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So that it won't recurse infinitely. The method could actually be removed. It is probably only there for backwards compatibility.